# WSO2 get user by claim value

Tags: wso2, user-management

I need to know how to get wso2 users by claim value, to perform some kind of search?

example:

`getUsersByClaimValue(String claimUri, String claimValue);`

Answer (score 6):

Yes.This API method has been introduced  to user store API to get user names associated with particular user's attribute. say you want to get users whose "country" attribute value is "USA". then you can use this method as follows.

`getUserList("http://wso2.org/claims/country", "USA", null);`

You can find this method as web service API in [RemoteUserStoreManagerService](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/)  of WSO2IS.  Your SOAP message would look likes follows.

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getUserList>
         <ser:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/country</ser:claimUri>
         <ser:claimValue>USA</ser:claimValue>
         <ser:profile></ser:profile>
      </ser:getUserList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Here, this claim uri is generic one which is independent of the user store. With WSO2 Identity server you can map these claim uri in to any attribute in your user store. More details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but I can't see such method in org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreManager.class. Should I have to use another class?

Comment: In above class you can find it as  getUserList("http://wso2.org/claims/country", "USA" ,"default"). Here third parameter is the profile. By default it would be "default" profile.   sorry i actually miss the method name... :)...

Comment: I've tried this but I'm getting an empty String[] every time.

Comment: This is the implementation in WSUserStoreManager.class
 @Override
    public String[] getUserList(String claim, String claimValue, String profileName)
                                                                        throws UserStoreException {
        // TODO
        return new String[0];
    }

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. There is now `UserStoreManager.listUsers` which takes some kind of query string.

Comment: Thanks.  Method name is not correct. Updated it.  However `listUser()` is just for listing all users, not to search by attribute.  It is not correct.

Comment: I finally found the method `getUserList`. It is defined in `core.UserStoreManager`, but not in `api.UserStoreManager`. A downcast fixed that (I got the UserStoreManager from an `api.UserRealm`). Should one be accessing `core` from web service client code?